# NoMatchingExpectationException even with $this->anything()

Tags: laravel-4, mockery

I'm writing a unit test for a Laravel controller method, but I keep getting NoMatchingExpectationExceptions no matter what I do with the `->with(...)`. The code under test:

```
public function destroy($id) {
  $foo = FooService::foo($id); //returns a Foo object (an Eloquent model)
  $fooCollection = new Collection(array($foo));
  $response = FooService::archive($fooCollection);

  return Response::json($response);
}
```

The unit test:

```
public function testArchiveSingle() {
  $foo = Mockery::mock('Foo', array('id' => 1));
  $fooCollection = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection();
  $fooCollection->add($foo);

  FooService::shouldReceive('foo')->once()
      ->with(1)
      ->andReturn($foo);

  //here's the shouldReceive that's throwing the error:
  FooService::shouldReceive('archive')->once()
      ->with($this->anything())
      ->andReturn(array('result'=>'here'));

  $response = $this->action('DELETE', 'FoosController@destroy',
      array('site' => 12345, 'foos' => 1),
      array());
  $this->assertResponseOk();
  $this->assertTrue($response->headers->contains('Content-Type', 'application/json'));
  //other tests that are proprietary in nature go here
}
```

In the `->with()` I've tried passing in `$fooCollection`, `$this->instanceOf('Collection')`, `$this->instanceOf('\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection')` and a few other things. I've also tried changing the `$fooCollection` definition to just `new Collection`.

When I run the tests, I get:

> Mockery\Exception\NoMatchingExpectationException : No matching handler found for Mockery_1_FooService::archive(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection). Either the method was unexpected or its arguments matched no expected argument list for this method

When I remove the `->with(...)` in the troublesome shouldReceive the test runs fine, but loses value since it wouldn't catch a (theoretical) bug that would accidentally archive too much.

Comment: Not really sure what `$this->anything()` is supposed to do? Try with `Mockery::any()`.

Comment: @BramGerritsen Aha. I slipped back into straight-up PHPUnit and that caused the problem. That worked, as did `Mockery::mustBe($fooCollection)`. If you'd like to submit that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Mockery::any()` to match for any argument. PHPUnit's own mock library uses `$this->anything()`. See the [manual](https://github.com/padraic/mockery/blob/master/docs/07-ARGUMENT-VALIDATION.md).

```
FooService::shouldReceive('archive')->once()
  ->with(Mockery::any())
  ->andReturn(array('result'=>'here'));
```